# embedding a pdf file on razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I am trying to embed a pdf file on a razor page. Below is the code in the controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ViewPDF()
        {
            string embed = "<object data=\"{0}\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"500px\" height=\"300px\">";
            embed += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = \"{0}\">here</a>";
            embed += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";
            embed += "</object>";
            TempData["Embed"] = `string.Format(embed,Url.Content("~/Documents/2022Packet.pdf"));`
    
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

      public IActionResult Index()
            {
            
                return View();
            }
```

Documents is in a folder in my application where I have pdf file called 2022Packet.pdf. below is the screen shot:

[image]

This is what I have in my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ViewPDF", "PDF", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();">View PDF</a>
        <hr />
    @Html.Raw(TempData["Embed"])
}
```

when I run my code, i see this screen shot instead of my pdf file

[image]

Is   Url.Content("~/Documents/2022Packet.pdf")); that I am using to display the pdf file wrong syntax to display the pdf file? Do I need to use absolutre URL or resolveURL to display the pdf file. This is the resulting HTML on browser:

```
<div class="container-bg">
        <div class="container">
            <main role="main" class="pb-3">
                <form action="/PDF/ViewPDF" method="post">        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();">View PDF</a>
        <hr />
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8CeXypSjYClBh-AvfVG-nwcQ_BEfVjwZg8BdU__NxjoQeke-Tc1mAO5wcURZ8FLNSZPXevyRML7o_nAHh2jwpec04_5ouAXFbTmUdt8YoxCSBy8WtvIMwF7badc7Yd4_blsULWgvxSRfS92lpJ4o7LE" /></form>
            </main>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For on-disk content, "~/" is the "wwwroot" directory in your project.

Comment: What is the resulting HTML in the browser for this?  In the browser's debugging tools, is a request made for the PDF?  What is that request?  What is the response?

Comment: Put the browser HTML in my post

Comment: Are you getting any error while clicking on it? It would be nicer if you could move your document folder inside wwwroot so that, webhostenvironment would easily allow you to access that file as well.

Comment: @rimi: The resulting HTML has no `<object>` element at all.  It sounds like the problem has nothing to do with whether or not the PDF is viewable or whether or not the URL for the PDF is correct (at least not yet), but rather that the code isn't outputting the markup you want *at all*.  You'll need to do some more debugging to narrow down what you're doing with `TempData` and why it isn't outputting anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is Url.Content("~/Documents/2022Packet.pdf")); that I am using to
> display the pdf file wrong syntax to display the pdf file? Do I need
> to use absolutre URL or resolveURL to display the pdf file. This is
> the resulting HTML on browser:

Well, to begin with your first question, yes its incorrect. In fact, it would not display your file as expected because in your `embed` html string at `data=\"{0}\"` you ought to pass file steream instead of file path. Finally, in your `string.Format` you have to pass your file path from where it would be read. Thus, your pdf has not been displayed.

**Solution:**

```
public class PDFController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _environment;


        public PDFController(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            _environment = environment;
           
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath, "Documents");
            // string path = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "Documents");
           
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
             
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path + "/YourFileName.pdf", stream.ToArray());

                string embed = "<object data=\"{0}\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"500px\" height=\"300px\">";
                embed += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = \"{0}\">here</a>";
                embed += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";
                embed += "</object>";

                TempData["Embed"] = string.Format(embed, "/Documents/YourFileName.pdf");
                return View();
            }
           
        }

    }
```

**Note:** If you wanted to read file from ourside of `wwwroot` use `_environment.ContentRootPath` but from inside `wwwroot` use `_environment.WebRootPath`. As you can see in my example. Then, in `string.formeter` pass your file path like this `string.Format(embed, "/Documents/YourFileName.pdf");` tild `~` is not required.

**Output:**

[image]

**Browser Seettings:**

If your browser restrict you, in that scenari, you should configure your browsere setting. For Eadge you can configure as following.

[image]

**Update:**

**Razor View:**

```
<div class="container-bg">
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            <a target="_blank" class="btn btn-info" asp-controller="PDF" asp-action="ViewPDF">Download PDF</a>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
@Html.Raw(TempData["Embed"])
```

Download PDF Controller:

While Download PDF would be clicked following controller would called.

```
public ActionResult ViewPDF()
        {
            string physicalPath = "wwwroot/Documents/YourPDFFileName.pdf";
            byte[] pdfBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(physicalPath);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(pdfBytes);

            string mimeType = "application/pdf";
            return new FileStreamResult(stream, mimeType)
            {
                FileDownloadName = "AnyNameYouWantToSet.pdf"
            };

        }
```

Comment: The MemoryStream is empty...

Comment: Why, are the files exists at the given location?

Comment: @Md Farid Uddin Kiron , can you please share your Razor file too where you are displaying the pdf.

Comment: Surely, please have a look on the updated part. Thanks.